# How to use boost::multiprecision::float128 in with Xcode

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, boost, clang++

I am trying to use boost::multiprecision::float128 in xCode project.

My compiler version is
Apple clang version 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.20.17)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin18.7.0
Thread model: posix

I am using boost.1.71.0

I am getting following compile error

> 'quadmath.h' file not found

in float128.hpp

```
extern "C" {
#include <quadmath.h>
}
```

I saw several threads regarding to this issue

- https://svn.boost.org/trac10/ticket/8265

  > 19 months ago by John Maddock (clang has no support for float128 and libquadmath, so you're out of luck: that header is supported by gcc and Intel compilers only.)
- https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/44405

As discussion threads I have find are few years old

- so is it still true that I can't use  boost::multiprecision::float128 in xCode project ?
- might it be something missing during boost setup, it has lib folder and during boost set up something get lost ?
- Is there any workaround for this problem, with my current compiler version?

Comment: Where/how is boost installed?  What is your header search path set to?

Comment: I have set up boost in my projects file structure, as I am going to use some part of boost I have used bcp to get .hpp files which I need. I think my header search path is set correct as I am able to use int128 without any problem. I got issue with float128 and it looks like there is issue with it for xcode. 
John Maddock commented under boost ticket around year ago clang has no support for float128 and libquadmath, so you're out of luck: that header is supported by gcc and Intel compilers only. 
But I am not sure is this still valid or maybe there is some way to workaround this since that.

Comment: Well `file not found` errors would seem to indicate an issue with set-up.  I would recommend you use a package manager like Homebrew in order to avoid managing the installation of boost on your system.

Comment: @trojanfoe thanks for recommendation, initially I used Homebrew and cocoapods but I had space issue and decided to use bcp tool to get only needed parts of boost. But this is not standard file not found error, it is know issue with boost with clang. I wrote here with hope that something might change recently.

Comment: Latest Intel compiler is based on Clang and appears to have lost libquadmath support along the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly, it's still not supported. There is more hope for "vanilla clang", than for Apple clang, but still, there's a lot of work to be done to make sure all the pieces are in place.

The issue to follow is [here](https://github.com/boostorg/math/issues/181), and [work has been done](https://github.com/boostorg/config/pull/261) to get it to compile with clang >=8. But Apple Clang still doesn't work.

As a workaround, you can use `boost::multiprecision::cpp_bin_float_quad`.

Comment: thanks for your answer but I don't think I can use boost::multiprecision::cpp_bin_float_quad for my case, I have boost int128 which I need to divide by float number.

Comment: You can't cast the int128 to a cpp_bin_float_quad?

Comment: I have just tested with cpp_bin_float_oct, it get compiled and it looks like value is casted correctly. I was under impression that  float128 in only data type in boost which supports 128 floating points numbers. And still I am not very clear how this  cpp_bin_float_oct works as I am very new in boost and the couldn't get it from https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/ref/cpp_bin_float_ref.html i

Comment: oct is twice the store of quad.