# R package requiring the 'libquadmath' library

Tags: r, boost, rcpp, cran

I made a R package which uses `Rcpp` and which requires the `libquadmath` library (to use the multiprecision numbers of `boost`). On my personal laptop (Ubuntu 18.04), it works "as is". On `win-builder` it works by setting `PKGLIBS = -lquadmath` or `PKGLIBS = $(FLIBS)` in the `Makevars` file. But I also checked on `r-hub` with these settings and for the Fedora Linux distribution (R-devel, clang, gfortran) I get a failure.

This failure is:

```
/home/docker/R/BH/include/boost/multiprecision/float128.hpp:40:10: fatal error: 'quadmath.h' file not found
```

So I'm fearing that my package will not pass the CRAN checks. What is the way to go?

Answer (score 3):

You write that you set "`PKGLIBS = -lquadmath` or `PKGLIBS = $(FLIBS)`". Those are *linker* instructions.

You write that `fatal error: 'quadmath.h' file not found`. That is a *compiler error*.

Now, the error comes from `float128.hpp` which happens to be in a package I maintain, so I took a quick look:

```
#if defined(BOOST_MP_USE_FLOAT128)

extern "C" {
#include <quadmath.h>
}
```

So you *could* suppress the inclusion by trying to ensure `BOOST_MP_USE_FLOAT128`.  Other than that, I would recommend to look at the Boost documentation for package multiprecision.  They may have a hint or two.

*Edit:* I took a quick peep at the multiprecision documentation but didn't see any leads. For other Boost libraries I have often started from some of the example but I am less familiar with this one.

*Edit 2:* Your example is also not exactly reproducible. I run Ubuntu here too, and the [Boost float128.cpp example](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/libs/math/example/float128_example.cpp) works fine on my box via `g++ -o fl128 fl128.cpp -lquadmath` (when save as `fl128.cpp`).  You may need to do some discovery in a `configure` script to see why the other Linux systems at RHub fail.

Comment: Thank you. The C/C++ world is not familiar to me. It looks like `clang` does not support `float128`: <https://github.com/boostorg/math/issues/181> <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57755032/how-to-use-boostmultiprecisionfloat128-in-with-xcode>

Comment: I am unfamiliar with what exactly `libquadmath` is -- but if (on your Ubunto box) you do `locate quadmath.h` you will see that it is in the include directories of gcc. Now does that mean `clang` cannot have it? I do not know. I also looked briefly into the two key R manuals (Inst+Admin, Writing R Ext.) and both only mention `quadmath` in passing.  Sorry, no better tips from me.

Comment: The more "meta" upshot may be that _Writing R Extensions_ warns us package developers quite a bit about portable code, and its limits. Maybe you just can't have 128bit doubles in a portable R package across all build systems?